# Sorting and querying using different containers, C++, STL

Tags: c++, performance, sorting, stl, time-complexity

Once when I was interviewing I was asked this question, and I consider the interviewer has mistaken.

Here is the question:

Consider we have a data type which has operator <. We have 2 choices.

1. To add all this data in the std::set and then querying and adding elements with std::find and std::insert. In this case the insertion of first N elements is N*logN, and each query and insertion is logN.
2. The second is to insert all this values in std::list, then sort it, and after query and insert with std::binary_search and insert. Here the insertion if N + sorting N*logN (according the interviewer) and each binary_search and insert logN.

I have answered that first case is faster, but the interviewer told me that as std::set is implemented via red-black trees, than the rebalancing is a expensive operation, thus the std::list case is faster. But after I noticed that sort for std::list can not be N*logN because it has no random access iterators.

Please help me finally understand which case is better and why?

Comment: A binary-search on a linked-list in O(log N)?  How does that work?

Comment: Yes, it is also an absurd, am I right?

Comment: And rebalancing isn't expensive operation at all. Actually it's complexity is amortized constant

Comment: So to answer the question of which is better; clearly the first option, because the second is ridiculous.

Comment: Are you sure the guy wasn't talking about `std::vector`s? That's the only way he could be right :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort on a list can be done in `O(n*log(n))` using `merge sort`. However there is a bigger problem - binary search can not be applied on the list precisely because of the lack of random access.

Still please note that a list can be implemented in many different ways, including using an array as backing and in that case you will also have random access(this is not the case with `std::list`, though).

The best solution to the problem is to use a `std::vector` and perform binary search on it(after you sort it). This way you know there is random access operator.

EDIT: as it seems the values in your container can change interactively, pre-sorting and then performing a binary search is not an option. It is so because after you insert a new value, you will have to sort the elements again. More complex version of list like skip list support that, but otherwise set should be faster by far.

Comment: Ok, and is the vector case faster the the set case?

Comment: @EduardRostomyan yes it will be. The interviewer was right that although both approaches are of the same computational complexity, a binary search is way simpler than manipulating a red-black tree. I think it is best that you write a simple benchmark test and try it yourself

Comment: Thanks, actually my interviewer was wrong, because he told that the list case is faster.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev And what about manipulating elements in `std::vector` when you want to insert into the middle of it? This will increase the insertion complexity to O(log N) + O(N) (searching + insertion)

Comment: @Erbureth my answer assumes that we first pre-process the array and then we only query for some elements. Assuming the values can change, than the set will be faster by far.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev The question explicitly states *and after query and insert*

Answer (score 0):

Yes the interviewer is wrong.

Yes you should continue interviewing until you find a better firm :-)